# How to connect to oracle using java on terminal/command line

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have a simple java program which connects to an oracle database and does a select query. In eclipse I added the jdbc jar file to the class path (had to google how to do it never used java before).
Now, I switched to my organizations terminal and when i run the program I get the error

```
java.sql.SQLException: "No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:"
  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
        at db.main(db.java:13)
```

I suspect that this is because I dont have the jdbc jar file anywhere. I was wondering how to go about doing this. I looked up adding stuff to the classpath but since it is my first time using java i dont even know what half of the posts mean.

Thanks

Comment: so now my eclipse is v 1.8  and my ssh environment is 1.6. how do i fix this? I had to get someone to manually put the jar file into my directory.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have ojdbc.jar in your machine. Also make sure its in the classpath. If its not add it to classpath. Then try to run your program again

Comment: yeah i think thats the problem i am sshed into the server and it doesnt exist there. I would need to ftp from my desktop to the server/ folder where i am right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what Oracle product you have. The most recent one I believe is 11.2.0.4. Below is the link to the most recent oracle drivers. Download the file and import it into your project. If you tell me what Oracle product you have and IDE you are using I am better able to assist you.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html

Comment: I am not using any IDEs right now just using vim to code. I think what i need to do is add the jdbc jar to my project but I dont know how to cause I am ssh'ed into a server. Thanks

Comment: I have little experience with connecting a driver in vim, but these steps might help. http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/mwm/Content/topics/databases/oracle.html

Comment: @user4992422 I couldn't comment on your post... It still should work if you are using eclipse. What is the error saying?

Comment: so now I have a totally different issue. My eclipse is version 1.8 of java  and the one on the server is 1.6 which implies that I cant run my jar file on there. Is there any way in eclipse to make it a java 1.6 jar? again, first time using eclipse and i have no clue how to make it work. thanks guys[

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there in that you understand what you need to do (tell Java where the Jars are that you wish to add to the classpath). I will try and explain with a sample application layout since this is just essentially about paths. Note that this example assumes you can find the Oracle jar (ODBC14.jar ?) on your filesystem. If you have managed to put it on the build path of your project in Eclipse then have a look under the Build preferences and you should be able to find its location.

```
project
    |
    |--target
    |      |
    |      |--classes
    |            |
    |            |--com
    |                 |
    |                 company
    |                     |
    |                    Main.class (package: com.company)
    |
    |--lib
         |
        odbc14.jar
```

Given the above layout, we can run the `Main.class` from a command as follows putting the Oracle jar on the classpath using the `cp` switch.

Windows example:

```
project> java -cp target\classes;lib\odbc14.jar com.company.Main
```

or, if we have multiple jars in `lib` (note the wildcard):

```
project> java -cp target\classes;lib\* com.company.Main
```

**A note on listing multiple Classpaths**

Note that the separator for separate paths is platform dependant.
Windows - use a semi-colon (;) to separate classpaths entries.
*Nix - use a colon (:) to separate classpaths entries.

windows example (note the semi-colon):

```
target/classes;target/dependencies/*
```

*nix example (note the colon):

```
 target/classes:target/dependencies/*
```